# What is the time complexity of deleting all array elements?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity

as we know, the time complexity of deleting an array element is o(n), so what is the time complexity of deleting the entire array?

i think is o(1), because the array address space is continuous. is my guess correct?

Comment: Which programming language are you talking about? In e.g. C or Haskell, arrays have a fixed size, so you cannot delete any elements.

Comment: I'd imagine it would depend on what's stored in the array and if each element requires destruction before the memory for the array can be deleted

Comment: @melpomene what about c?

Comment: @richer: As melpomene already wrote in the first comment, in C, arrays have a fixed size, so you cannot delete an element.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag How long does it take for the system to recycle the array?

Comment: What kind of array? Please be specific.

Comment: @richer: What system? What does "recycle" mean? What is your machine model? What is your cost model? It doesn't make sense to ask about "time complexity" without a cost model and machine model.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the array itself would be O(1) because it would simply release the memory to the pool while deleting every item in the array would be O(n) because each item needs to be removed individually.

There are exceptions, some implementations may for example use an algorithm that clears memory in chunks larger than the size of each item in the array (which would be O(n/c) where c is how many times bigger a chunk is compared to an item in the array), and some languages might simply release the original array and have pointers point to a new empty array which would be O(1). The above answer however is assuming a naive implementation.